# Using VBA to click on a button that has no "Id" nor "Value" I i can use to click

Tags: vba

I have tried different methods such as using trying to use the tab key to get to it but unfortunately it is not in the tabbing sequences, so I could not send the focus on it to be have my RPA click on it. Below is the HTML markup:

```
<td class="buttonSmall" onmouseout="this.className='buttonSmall'" 
   onmousedown="this.className='buttonSmallPressed'" 
   onmouseup="this.className='buttonSmall'" 
   onclick="openDualFacingWindow(getBillingCycleURL());">View</td>
```

Notice that I have tried to use the tag as follow

```
Set viewObject = Ie.document.getElementsByTagName("td")
For Each viewObj In viewObject
    If viewObj.Value = "View" Then
        viewObj.onclick
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

It does not seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `If viewObj.innerText = "View" Then`

Comment: Thank you Tim for responding to my question. I tried it but it does not work still.

Comment: Try `viewObj.click` and if that doesn't work you will need to do some debugging: does that line even get triggered for example?

Comment: Sorry, again for taking that long to respond. I have been working fixing other part of the codes. Before submitting the question i did try the viewOjc.click and did not work either. In regard to your suggestion about debugging all the times that I have been trying to fix it was always in debugging mode as the code is already in production and I have to it live. There is no dummy case available, only live cases and I usually have to wait for a particular case to try it. Thank you again for trying.